# What is the purpose of a static "DELETE" object?

Tags: java, android

In the Android class [SparseArray](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/util/SparseArray.java/), a static final variable `DELETED` is defined as a simple `Object`. Later in the class its reference is used as an identifier for deleted entities that were added to the container. Why are deleted entities not just nulled out? What is the purpose of differentiating between a null slot and a deleted slot?

Note: while directly asking about the SparseArray class, the question is in general.

Comment: If you used `null` instead, how would you distinguish between deleted items and actual `null` values added to the array?

Comment: @verdesmarald What is the point of distinguishing between the two?

Comment: @Simulant Not an android question. Truthfully this is a language agnostic question.

Comment: See my answer for an explanation.

Comment: @verdesmarald yup, just waiting on answer accept timer to end. +1 for good answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because `null` is a valid value to store in the array, so you need to be able to distinguish between `null` and `DELETED`.

As an example of why you need to distinguish them, consider `get(key, default)`:

```
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 public E get(int key, E valueIfKeyNotFound) {
     int i = binarySearch(mKeys, 0, mSize, key);

     if (i < 0 || mValues[i] == DELETED) {
         return valueIfKeyNotFound;
     } else {
         return (E) mValues[i];
     }
 }
```

Now if you do something like:

```
array.put(1, null);
array.get(1, someDefault);
```

You will (correctly) get `null`.

If you replace `DELETED` with `null`, you would get `someDefault` instead.